# How to prove that the horizontal composition of natural isomorphisms is still a natural isomorphism

Tags: category-theory

If we consider the horizontal composition of

[image]

that is the diagram

[image]

If $\theta$ and $\phi$ are natural isomorphisms, then $\phi_{F_1(X)}$ and $\theta_X$ is invertible, but $G_2$ is not invertible. I am wondering why is the horizontally composed natural isomorphisms $\phi*\theta$ is a natural isomorphism? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A functor sends isomorphisms into isomorphisms. More precisely, you can express horizontal composition with whiskerings, and if $\alpha$ is a natural isomorphism, for every functor $F,G$ that can be whiskered with $\alpha$, $\alpha * F$ and $G * \alpha$ are natural isomorphisms (careful: what I denote $*$ is not what you denote $*$).

Comment: Thank you! I think I get it, finally.